# Short IF - ELSE statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to make my code more readable, so I decided to use some short IF statements.

Here's my code which doesn't work ("not a statement"):

```
jXPanel6.isVisible() ? jXPanel6.setVisible(true) : jXPanel6.setVisible(false);
```

What's wrong with this? Needs brackets? Where?

Comment: Although mautetto has provided a better way of writing this, this structure is usually called a ternary operator. ( In case you were wondering ;) )

Comment: It's the **conditional** operator.  "Ternary" just means it has 3 operands.

Comment: Link to language specification for conditional operator: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The "ternary expression" `x ? y : z` can only be used for conditional *assignment*.  That is, you could do something like:

```
String mood = inProfit() ? "happy" : "sad";
```

because the ternary expression is returning something (of type `String` in this example).

It's not really meant to be used as a short, in-line `if-else`.  In particular, you can't use it if the individual parts don't return a value, or return values of incompatible types.  (So while you could do this if both method happened to return the same value, you *shouldn't* invoke it for the side-effect purposes only).

So the proper way to do this would just be with an if-else block:

```
if (jXPanel6.isVisible()) {
    jXPanel6.setVisible(true);
}
else {
    jXPanel6.setVisible(false);
}
```

which of course can be shortened to

```
jXPanel6.setVisible(jXPanel6.isVisible());
```

Both of those latter expressions are, for me, more readable in that they more clearly communicate what it is you're trying to do.  (And by the way, did you get your conditions the wrong way round?  It looks like this is a no-op anyway, rather than a toggle).

Don't mix up *low character count* with *readability*.  The key point is what is most easily understood; and mildly misusing language features is a definite way to confuse readers, or at least make them do a mental double-take.

Comment: It is simply not true that you can only use the conditional operator for assignment.  You can use it anywhere an expression is required.

Answer (score 28):

```
jXPanel6.setVisible(jXPanel6.isVisible());
```

or in your form:

```
jXPanel6.setVisible(jXPanel6.isVisible()?true:false);
```

Comment: FWIW, I feel that there's *never* a need to write `<bool condition> ? true : false` because it's exactly equivalent to just `<bool condition>`.

Comment: Obviously! But monczek asked about Short If-Else statement so I coded it just to show the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

The ternary operator can only be the right side of an assignment and not a statement of its own.

http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018/

Comment: It is not true that the conditional operator can only be used on the RHS of an assignment. It can be used anywhere an expression can be used.

Answer (score 3):

As others have indicated, something of the form

```
x ? y : z
```

is an expression, not a (complete) statement. It is an rvalue which needs to get used someplace - like on the right side of an assignment, or a parameter to a function etc.

Perhaps you could look at this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party but for future readers.

From what i can tell, you're just wanting to toggle the visibility state right? Why not just use the `!` operator?

```
jxPanel6.setVisible(!jxPanel6.isVisible);
```

It's not an if statement but I prefer this method for code related to your example.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to toggle the state, i think that the statement is backwards. Is this why it didn't work? Should it be jXPanel6.isVisible() ? jXPanel6.setVisible(false) : jXPanel6.setVisible(true);

Comment: If it's not a toggle statement then I don't understand the purpose of making something visible that's already set that way. The isVisible retrieves the state and the setVisible sets the state, right? If the isVisible statement returns true, why set it to true again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as simple as this, I did it in react hooks :

```
 (myNumber == 12) ? "true" : "false"
```

it was equal to this long if function below :

```
if (myNumber == 12) {
  "true"
} else {
  "false"
}
```

Hope it helps ^_^