# Can anyone tell me what exactly this code means in c#?

Tags: c#

Particularly the symbols ? : And how can I use them in other ways

```
Console.WriteLine("The rectangle with edges [{0},{1}] is {2}a square" ,
                r3.Edge1, r3.Edge2, (r3.IsSquare()) ? "" : "not ");
```

Comment: It is *conditional ternary operator*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short IF - ELSE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461996/short-if-else-statement)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, guys! They were all really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, ? is a ternary operator.

So to answer the actual question,

```
Console.WriteLine("The rectangle with edges [{0},{1}] is {2}a square" ,
                r3.Edge1, r3.Edge2, (r3.IsSquare()) ? "" : "not ");
```

{0} and {1} will be replaced with the values of r3.Edge1 and r3.Edge2, respectively, when that line is written to the console.
r3.IsSquare() is likely returning a boolean, so if it returns true, it'll write nothing (empty string "") but if it returns false, it'll write "not ".

So for example, the final result, assuming r3.IsSquare() returns false, would look like `The rectangle with edges[3, 6] is not a square`, if it had returned true, then it would say `The rectangle with edges[3, 6] is a square`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said conditional operator (?) does [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx),

> If condition is `true`, first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is `false`, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result

And inputs are given in following format,

> condition ? first_expression : second_expression;

In your case parameters are as follow ,

```
  condition  =  r3.IsSquare()  // <= return a Boolean I guess
  first_expression = ""    // Empty string
  second_expression = not  // word `not`
```

So in your case what does code `(r3.IsSquare()) ? "" : "not ")`  does,

- If `r3` is a square, output is `""` which is empty string.
- If `r3` is not a square , output is the word `not`

Note that method `IsSquare()` called upon `r3` should return a Boolean (true or false) value.

Same condition evaluated on a console program,

```
    // if r3.IsSquare() return true
    Console.WriteLine((true ? "" : "not")); // <= Will out an empty
    // if r3.IsSquare() return false
    Console.WriteLine((false ? "" : "not")); // will out the word `not`

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Simple example

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input > 0)
    classify = "positive";
else
    classify = "negative";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input > 0) ? "positive" : "negative";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternary operator. The basic way it works is like this:

```
bool thingToCheck = true;
var x = thingToCheck ? "thingToCheck is true" : "thingToCheck is false";
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

[MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)