# Short if statement usage

Tags: java, python

In python i can do following:

```
return x or y
```

or

```
my_function(x or y)
```

if `x != null` or not empty will return or pass `x` else `y`.

My question:

There is way do this in java shorten then
`return x == null ? y : x` or

```
myFunction(x == null ? y : x)
```

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: I'm not even sure `x || y` is valid as an expression in _any_ python version, it's normally `x if x else y`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, you're right, it isn't, that is why I asked

Comment: But that still doesn't help us try to figure out what your goal is in Java :)

Comment: Maybe => return (x==null ? y:z )

Comment: i updated my question, maybe now it is more clearly.

Comment: @Tany, maybe if you wrote valid python it might help, do you mean `return x or y`? i.e if x is Falsey return whatever y is?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the ternary method is the most efficient and shortest. But, if you want to go further and shorten things up, you could just create a generic static or non-static method, depending on your situation, to validate the two objects. Then just return the validated method, instead of the ternary condition. Something like this for example.

```
//usage
Employee valid(Employee x, Employee y) {
    return v(x,y);
}

//generic method for validation
<T> T v(T o1, T o2) {
    return o1==null?o2:o1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think what you wanted to do is passing the resulting value from

x==null ? y : x

as argument to a function.

I found this on Stack Overflow:
[Short IF - ELSE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461996/short-if-else-statement) .
Maybe this will help.

In short: myFunction(x==null ? y : x); should work fine.

Comment: yes, but my question, there is way do it shorten than myFunction(x==null ? y : x) like in python