# Keep ArrayList sorted after every add call by finding index to add Integer very quickly (1 million add calls needed)

Tags: java

My teacher wants me to add an Integer item one at a time to a generic arraylist inside MySortedArray Class. I have to add 1_000_000 items. The custom add method he wants me to implement in MySortedArray, needs to add able to sort the arraylist after every addition. However, sorting it a million times after every add() call is too slow. What am I supposed to do? I need to be able to find the index in the ArrayList where I should add the Integer item very quickly. Would binary search work?

```
    @Test
    void testRandomInts() {
        MySortedArray<Integer> ints = new MySortedArray<>(10);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            int num = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            ints.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println("array is: " + ints.contents.toString());
        assertTrue(isSorted(ints));
    }
```

Comment: Use a LinkedList instead?

Comment: My teacher is forcing us to use an ArrayList :(
MySortedArray Class does implement Comparable, so I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be using the compareTo method to find the index where I would add the item. But, I need to find the index really fast.

Comment: Your teacher is probably intending for you to use a binary search to figure out which index to insert the next element at.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do a binary search?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: Cause I got this error before:
The method binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>, T) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (MySortedArray<T>, 
 T)

Comment: Why do you want to use the `MySortedArray`? If it is necessary for you, can you post this class? It is necessary that this class import the `Comparator` interface.

Comment: We aren't supposed to use Comparator for this lab. The class only extends Comparable.
public class MySortedArray <T extends Comparable<T>>  implements GenericSortedArray<T> {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  int index = Collections.binarySearch(contents, item);
  if (index < 0) index = ~index;
  contents.add(index, item);
```

Comment: You can simplify your code a little bit with a [short-if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461996/short-if-else-statement).

Comment: Code-only answers are flagged as low-quality. Can you add a brief explanation of how this works and why it's a good solution to the problem? Thanks!